# Loop through XMLList - strange behaviour

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, xmllist

I'm trying to loop through an XMLList and rather than giving me each item in the list as XML, it's just coming back with the positions as strings e.g.

`var myList:XMLList = ...   (contains <Animal><Type>Dog</Type></Animal><Animal><Type>Cat</Type></Animal>)`

```
for(var item in myList) {
    Alert.show(item);               
}
```

It just alerts "0" or "1". If I inspect the 'item' variable, I see the same thing. But if I inspect 'myList' it looks like the XML.

I've also tried myList.children() and strongly typing 'items' to 'XML' but nothing I do has worked.

Would really appreciate it if someone can tell me the right way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `for each` instead of `for`

Answer (score 1):

As it is returning indexes you can just reference them in the list directly:

```
   for(var item in myList) {   
     var xml:XML = myList[item] as XML;
     trace(xml);        
   }
```

This will print out the following:

```
<Animal>
  <Type>Dog</Type>
</Animal>
<Animal>
  <Type>Cat</Type>
</Animal>
```

Or, you can reference elements of each child directly:

```
    for (var child : Object in myList.children()) {
      var xml : XML = myList[child];
      trace(xml.Type);
    }
```

Which results in:

```
Dog
Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to get just Dog and Cat.

```
for each (var item:Object in myList)
            {
                trace(item.children()[0]);
            }
```